# How to change css for span in span?

Tags: css

I want that Article 4 have one font family and News have another. How can i achive that? When i put font family on first and second inherit it.

```
<span><span class="useWord-first">News</span> Article 4</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the CSS on the parent `span` element, and then override that CSS by using a more specific selector to style the nested `.useWord-first` element.

For instance:

```css
span {
  color: #f00;
  font-family: monospace;
}
span > .useWord-first {
  color: #00f;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<span><span class="useWord-first">News</span> Article 4</span>
```

Comment: thats it :) i can accept your answer for 9 minutes :D

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
span {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
}
span > span.useWord-first {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the descendant selector along with the child's class to be as specific as possible:

```
span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
span > span.useWord-first {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fa46pzbx/1/